# $|a| - |b - a| \leq |b|$

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

How would you prove that $|a| - |b - a| \leq |b|$ for all $a, b \in \mathbb R$? I've tried several methods so far like the triangle inequality, but nothing seems to work. Can someone please help?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That is the triangle inequality. Set $b-a=x$ and $a=y$. What does the triangle inequality say about $x+y$?

Answer (score 5):

First, write: 
\begin{align*}
|a| = |a + 0| = |(a - b) + b|.
\end{align*}
Using the triangle inequality:
\begin{align*}
|a| \leq |a-b| + |b|
\end{align*}
Noting that $|a - b| = |b-a|$, write: 
\begin{align*}
|a| \leq |b- a| + |b|.
\end{align*}
Subtracting $|b - a|$ gives
\begin{align*}
|a| - |b-a| \leq |b|.
\end{align*}

Answer (score 1):

We have that

$$|a| - |b - a| \leq |b| \iff |a| \le|b|+ |b - a|$$

then let $a=x+y$ and $b=y$ to obtain

$$|x+y| \le|y|+ |x|$$

which is the triangle inequality.

Comment: Or $|a| = |(a-b)+b| \le |a-b| + |b|$.

Comment: @Milten Yes that's also fine!