# Proof verification $|x+y| \leq |x| + |y|$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

Here's my proof:

Suppose $|x+y|\leq |x|+|y|$

we know that   $-(|x|+|y|)\leq|x+y|\leq|x|+|y|$

1st case: When $x$ and $y$ are negative we get $-(x+y)\leq -(x+y)\leq x+y$
. If we divide by $x+y$ we get $-1\leq-1 \leq1 $ which is true.

2nd case: When $x$ and $y$ are positive by the same reasoning we get $-1\leq 1\leq 1$ which is true.

so from the two cases we conclude that $|x+y|\leq|x|+|y|$

Am I missing something ?

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Case 1: $x$ and $y$ are both positive and Case 2: $x$ and $y$ are both negative.  are not all the possible cases.  What if one or both are $0$ what if on is positive and the other is negative.  What if one is negative and the other is $0$.  What if.....

Comment: I believe that the only case i am missing is if one negative and one is positive since if both or one of them is 0 is already proved because x and y are in R

Comment: "Suppose $|x+y|= |x|+|y|$"  That's what we need to prove.  We can't suppose that.  ....  "if we divide by x+y we get -1<=-1<=1 which is true."   So what?   That doesn't mean what you were supposing was true is true.  Suppose $12=8$.  Then subtract $10$ and square and you get $2=-2$ and $4 = 4$.  Which is true.  .... That does not mean $12=8$.

Comment: yes you have a valid point

Comment: Possible duplicate of [$|a| - |b - a| \leq |b|$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3418366/a-b-a-leq-b)

Comment: In the first case, if $x$ and $y$ are negative, $-(x+y)$ is gonna be positive,  so it makes no sense that $-(x+y) \leq x+y$, moreover, since $x$ and $y$ are negative, $(x+y)$ is negative, so if you divide by $(x+y)$, the inequality changes direction

Answer (score 0):

1. If $x,y\ge 0$, then $|x+y| = x+y = |x|+|y|$.
2. If $x,y\le 0$, then $x+y \le 0$ and thus $|x+y| = -(x+y) = (-x)+(-y) = |x|+|y|$.
3. Let $x\le 0\le y$. Then $x+y = |y|-|x|$.

   3.1. If $|y|-|x|\ge 0$, then $|x+y| = |y|-|x|\le |y|+|x|$.

   3.2. If $|y|-|x| < 0$, then $|x+y| = -(|y|-|x|) = |x|-|y|\le |x|+|y|$.
4. If $y\le 0\le x$, then this is 3. with $x$ and $y$ swapped. So, we get the same result.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are missing some cases and you have made some mistakes so far.

Note that if  both x and y are negative then $$-(|x|+|y|)\leq|x+y|\leq|x|+|y|$$  is equivalent to

$$ x+y\le -x-y\le -x-y $$ and if they are both positive it is equivalent to $$-x-y\le x+y\le x+y $$

And you have not considered  the case where one is positive and the other one is negative.

Answer (score 0):

Let $a= \min(|x|,|y|)$ and $b=\max(|x|, |y|)$.

Then  $0\le a \le b$ and $0 \le b-a \le a+b$

If $x$ and $y$ are both non-negative or both negative then: $|x+y|=|\pm(a+b)|=a+b =|x|+|y|$.

$x$ and $y$ are "mixed" that is one is negative and one is non-negative then: $|x+y| = |\pm a \mp b|=b-a \le a+b = |x| + |y|$.

And that's it.